# How to exchange items position in pyqt by drag&drop

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I use `QtGui.QGraphicsItem` as my base class(in fact, I'm considering `QtGui.QGraphicsWidget` instead), and expect items in `QtGui.QGraphicsView` can exchange their position simply by drag&drop.

In one word: drag A to B, and exchange their positions.

My Question is: how can i get A's position in the drag&drop event and how can i return B's position to A.

now I have got how to seal location in stream,but is there a way more pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`dragMoveEvent`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qgraphicsitem.html#dragMoveEvent) Slot where you get a [`QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qgraphicsscenedragdropevent.html)

This has the Public Functions

```
QPointF     pos () const
QPointF     scenePos () const
QPoint      screenPos () const
```

which you can use to get the Position Information that you need.

**EDIT**

The Drag&Drop Puzzle [Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/draganddrop-puzzle.html) shows all the information you need for drag&drop.

Comment: I have read the Example, but it dosn't provide a way to convey B's position to A. I know I can emit a signal when A is droped and connected to a function in QtGui.QGraphicsView which search A with A's position...ect. Is there a better way?

Comment: I would do it like this: On Drag A start: save starting position. On Drop Evenet on B: set A to Bs position and set Bs position to start position.

Comment: I still have problem with how to "On Drop Evenet on B: set A to Bs position". I can't get Which object is A in B' Drop Event so that I couldn't control A in B's DropEvent ,and the document says QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent.source() returns the QGraphicsView that created the QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent. However, I got an unknowen QWidget